# Override JS function from bundle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

My Angularjs website has been compile using webpack.

In the chrome console, i want to override a function from the controller of a specific directive. Is it possible ?

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: I am looking at building a tool to push a hotfix in frontend code. This would avoid me in emergency situation to do a full release build and redeploy on the server

Comment: A build and deploy shouldn't last more than a few minutes with automated pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you meant inspector and not console, this should be possible.
Firstly, your code bundler must have had source mapping enabled when the code was built though.  For webpack pass the argument `--devtool source-map`, as documented here [https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)/.

Second enable overrides in the inspector:

Sources tab > overrides tab > Select folder for overrides (make a special folder for this) > allow in browser alert.

Now you can file the source file you want to edit in the sources tab and edit, then ctrl+s to save.  It will save the changes to a local copy of the file and override the requested file with it.

Happy debugging.